# `foreach` in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

This code type-checks:

```hs
type T :: Type -> foreach (r :: Type) -> Type -> Type
data T k r a

type T' :: Type -> Type
type T' a = T a Identity a
```

- Why is it that the compiler requires a type of kind `Type -> Type` (ie., `Identity`) here? It fails to type-check if you replace `Identity` with say `Int`.
- What is `foreach` keyword, and how does one use it in Haskell?

Comment: `forall` is a keyword, `foreach` is not, it's just a type variable like `f`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a keyword, just an implicitly quantified type variable. It's like when you write a function

```
foo :: Int -> foreach r -> Double
foo = undefined

main = print ( foo 123 (Just 'w')
             , foo 789 [False, True, False] )
```

...so `foreach r` can be unified with `Maybe Char` or `[Bool]` but not, for instance, `Float`.

Now, in your example it's even more weird, because you have *not* applied `Identity` to anything. That means the `foreach` type in `T a Identity a` seems to be actually the partially applied `->` operator from `Identity`s `Type -> Type` signature lifted up one level... funky stuff.

Comment: *faceslap* of course! `foreach` *will* become a keyword though, as part of [dependent haskell](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/dependent-haskell).

Comment: The name hasn't been decided and there will be a community discussion

Comment: You will be interested in [Dependent Types in Haskell: Theory and Practice](https://repository.brynmawr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1074&context=compsci_pubs), especially *Figure 4.1* which lists the quantifiers of Dependent Haskell. `foreach->` corresponds to the visible dependent relevant (unmatchable) quantifier